# The table content is disappeared after sorting

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sorting, html-table

I'm new to ReactJS. I have created a table with 2 columns. Here is my initial code:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import { getUsers } from '../../services/userService'
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom'

const Table = () => {

    const navigate = useNavigate()

    const [users, setUsers] = useState([]);
    const [currentUsers, setCurrentUsers] = useState([]);
    const [search, setSearch] = useState('');

    useEffect(async () => {
        try {
            const response = await getUsers(search);
            setUsers(response.data.users);
        } catch (error) { }
    }, [search]);
    
    return (
        <div dir='rtl' className='bg-background mt-10 px-5 rd1200:px-30 overflow-auto'>

            <table className='w-full border-separate rounded-md'>
                <thead>
                    <tr className='bg-text-secondary text-white shadow-sm text-center'>
                        <th className='p-2'>name</th>
                        <th className='p-2'>phone</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    {currentUsers.map((item, index) =>
                        <tr key={item.id} className={index % 2 === 0 ? 'bg-white shadow-sm text-center' : 'bg-text bg-opacity-5 shadow-sm text-center'}>
                            <td className='text-text text-sm p-2'>{item.name}</td>
                            <td className='text-text text-sm p-2'>{item.phone}</td>
                        </tr>
                    )}
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Table
```

I'm trying to sort this table by clicking on each column header. So I changed my code and here is the final code:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import { getUsers } from '../../services/userService'
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom'

const Table = () => {

    const navigate = useNavigate()

    const [users, setUsers] = useState([]);
    const [currentUsers, setCurrentUsers] = useState([]);
    const [search, setSearch] = useState('');
    const [sorting, setSorting] = useState({ key: "name", ascending: true });

    useEffect(async () => {
    try {
        const response = await getUsers(search);
        setUsers(response.data.users);
        setPageCount(Math.ceil(response.data.users.length / pageItemCount))
        setCurrentUsers(response.data.users.slice(0, pageItemCount))
    } catch (error) { }
}, [search]);

    /**************************************** */
    useEffect(() => {
        const currentUsersCopy = [...currentUsers];
    
        const sortedCurrentUsers = currentUsersCopy.sort((a, b) => {
          return a[sorting.key].localeCompare(b[sorting.key]);
        });
    
        setCurrentUsers(
          sorting.ascending ? sortedCurrentUsers : sortedCurrentUsers.reverse()
        );
    }, [currentUsers, sorting]);

    function applySorting(key, ascending) {
        setSorting({ key: key, ascending: ascending });
    }

    /************************************** */

const changePage = (i) => {
    setCurrentPage(i)
    const startItem = ((i - 1) * pageItemCount) + 1
    setCurrentUsers(users.slice(startItem - 1, (pageItemCount * i)))
}

const handleChange = (event, value) => {
    changePage(value);
}

    return (
        <div dir='rtl' className='bg-background mt-10 px-5 rd1200:px-30 overflow-auto'>

            <table className='w-full border-separate rounded-md'>
                <thead>
                    <tr className='bg-text-secondary text-white shadow-sm text-center'>
                        <th className='p-2' onClick={() => applySorting('name', !sorting.ascending)}>name</th>
                        <th className='p-2' onClick={() => applySorting('name', !sorting.ascending)}>phone</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    {currentUsers.map((item, index) =>
                        <tr key={item.id} className={index % 2 === 0 ? 'bg-white shadow-sm text-center' : 'bg-text bg-opacity-5 shadow-sm text-center'}>
                            <td className='text-text text-sm p-2'>{item.name}</td>
                            <td className='text-text text-sm p-2'>{item.phone}</td>
                        </tr>
                    )}
                </tbody>
            </table>
        <Pagination className="mt-2 pb-20" dir='ltr' page={currentPage} count={pageCount} onChange={handleChange} variant="outlined" shape="rounded" />

        </div>
    )
}    
export default Table
```

The problem is that when I changed my code, the content of my table disappeared. Although the entered users still exists and are added to my database, they are not displayed in the database. What's wrong?

Comment: You are settings the users API response to `users` state and not using it. Probably if you change this part of code `const currentUsersCopy = [...currentUsers];` to `const currentUsersCopy = [...users];` it will work

Comment: @LuisPauloPinto It didn't solve the problem. The page content appears for a second and then page become white & blank.

Comment: Maybe the problem its in the api call? take a look into this [codesample](https://codesandbox.io/s/stack-table-test-xmbkjj?file=/src/Table.jsx). I just removed de api call and added some mock data.

Answer (score 1):

@Валера Битковский is right, there are a few things:

1. you should sort the users and not the current users to avoid an infinite loop
2. there is no need to have a `currentUsers` state - it is derived from the users + sort state.
3. `useEffect` runs after the render, there is no need for it if you are reacting to your own state change, useMemo runs during the render only if the dependencies changed.

I'll just rewrite your code to make it simpler

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import { getUsers } from '../../services/userService'
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom'

const Table = () => {

const navigate = useNavigate()

const [users, setUsers] = useState([]);
const [search, setSearch] = useState('');
const [sorting, setSorting] = useState({ key: "name", ascending: true });

useEffect(async () => {
    try {
        const response = await getUsers(search);
        setUsers(response.data.users);
    } catch (error) { }
}, [search]);

/**************************************** */
const sortedUsers = useMemo(() => {
    const sortedCurrentUsers = [...users].sort((a, b) => {
      return a[sorting.key].localeCompare(b[sorting.key]);
    });

    return sorting.ascending ? sortedCurrentUsers : sortedCurrentUsers.reverse();
}, [users, sorting]);



function applySorting(key, ascending) {
    setSorting({ key: key, ascending: ascending });
}

/************************************** */

return (
    <div dir='rtl' className='bg-background mt-10 px-5 rd1200:px-30 overflow-auto'>

        <table className='w-full border-separate rounded-md'>
            <thead>
                <tr className='bg-text-secondary text-white shadow-sm text-center'>
                    <th className='p-2' onClick={() => applySorting('name', !sorting.ascending)}>name</th>
                    <th className='p-2' onClick={() => applySorting('name', !sorting.ascending)}>phone</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                {sortedUsers.map((item, index) =>
                    <tr key={item.id} className={index % 2 === 0 ? 'bg-white shadow-sm text-center' : 'bg-text bg-opacity-5 shadow-sm text-center'}>
                        <td className='text-text text-sm p-2'>{item.name}</td>
                        <td className='text-text text-sm p-2'>{item.phone}</td>
                    </tr>
                )}
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
)
}    
export default Table
```

Comment: The reason why I have used `currentUsers` is that I wanted to apply paging and display for example 15 users in the first page, next 15 users in the next page, etc. I had removed that part of the code here, for easier debug. I edited my final code and added the whole code.

Comment: By the way, the suggested code doesn't work for me.  When I run the backend code, the page turns to a blank page with no content.

Comment: I don't understand what does "run the backend code" means.. and can't debug for you :) but here is a link to a codesandbox with what I suggested - https://codesandbox.io/s/strange-panka-g5rtek?file=/src/Table.js

Comment: the main problem in your code is that you have an endless loop `useEffect(() => setCurrentUsers(...), [currentUsers])` can't work. and you can do what I suggested with `currentUsers` if you need to

Comment: btw, `useMemo` is used only for optimization, it will work without it

Comment: @Alissa is completely right - I would add though that for `currentUsers` it's _still_ derived state, even if you apply paging and what not afterwards. The search is complete, the data you got from the BE is now stored in your `users` state. If you want to do pagination, you can do it by having another state `activePageNumber`, then use that page number + all users to get the subarray you have to render.

Answer (score 0):

I would not recommend that you constantly change the original array, this is unreliable, try rewriting useEffect. I'm guessing that since you're constantly calling setCurrentUsers this changes the reference to currentUsers and triggers useEffect again as the dependency reference has changed and your code is cycling.
try something like this to reach your goals:

```
const sortedUsers = useMemo(() => {
    const currentUsersCopy = [...currentUsers];
    const sortedCurrentUsers = currentUsersCopy.sort((a, b) => {
       return a[sorting.key].localeCompare(b[sorting.key]);
     });
     return sorting.ascending ? sortedCurrentUsers : sortedCurrentUsers.reverse();
}, [sorting, currentUsers])
```

This way you only sort users if new data arrives or sorting is updated.

Including I don’t see the place where you update the `currentUsers`, which you use to render the list, you save data from the api only in `users`

You can also leave the logic with useEffect, but remember that if you change the state based on the previous value, then do not use it directly on, but instead use the callback inside setState:

```
setState((prevState) => /* sorting logic */)
```

https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates

Comment: so where I'm going to call `sortedUsers`? I receive this warning right now: `'sortedUsers' is assigned a value but never used`

Comment: So just use this variable to render table instaed of `currentUsers`